# Jekyll - How to use a markdown file in a parent folder

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I have a github repository with a Github Page website activated structured as followed:

```
/
|__README.md
|__docs/
   |__ _config.yml
   |__ stylesheets
   |__ javascripts
   |__ images
   |__ index.md
```

The files docs/index.md and README.md are stricly identical. How could I set README.md file as the "index" file with Jekyll ? Or at least make index.md include README.md ?

I tried the following and it does not work:

```
# First try
{% include ../README.md %}

# Second attempt
{% include_relative ../README.md %}
```

For the record, I use the theme: jekyll-theme-architect

Answer (score 1):

You may set `permalink` by front matter in `README.md` to generate as `index.html`:

```
---
permalink: index.html
---
```

Comment: README.md is not in the jekyll folder. It's the root README file. Unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I think it not available to include file not in `docs`.

Comment: IMO, you may write a `Rakefile` to build README.md into to `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I tried in the index.markdown file to add `{% include_relative README.md %}` and it worked perfectly. The file has only that by the way:

```
---
# Feel free to add content and custom Front Matter to this file.
# To modify the layout, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults

layout: home
---
{% include_relative README.md %}
```